# How do I loop through an array for a particular value in CoffeeScript

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I am trying to loop through an array with CoffeeScript to pull out the `full_name` value as shown below. I've been all over Stack overflow and CoffeeScript's docs the last few days and can't figure it out. This is what I currently have. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Angular JS

```
<disabled-display template="{{ctrl.getTechnicianNames()}}">
```

CoffeeScript

```
ctrl.getTechnicianNames = (full_name) ->
    array_of_persons = ctrl.technicians
    ctrl.getTechnicianNames full_name for full_name in array_of_persons
```

ctrl.technicians

```
{email: "email@address.com", first_name: "John", full_name: "John Johnson",
last_name: "Johnson"}, 
{email: "address@email.com", first_name: "Frank", full_name: "Frank Franklin",
last_name: "Franklin"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a much more coffeescripty way:

```coffee
ctrl.technitianNames = -> (t.full_name for t in @technicians)
```

Note the avoidance of the `get` prefix. It is considered a code smell in (to my knowledge most) languages other than Java and C++.

Comment: Note I dropped the `get` prefix b/c to my best knowledge it tends to be a code smell in languages other than Java and C++.

Comment: Yes! I assumed this was part of your decision. I ended up using `show` instead of `get`, but that could also be a code smell!

Answer (score 1):

```coffee
ctrl.getTechnicianNames = ->
    ctrl.technicians.map((technician) => technician.full_name)
```

Nothing specific to CoffeeScript about it, you just want `Array.prototype.map`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map